# Defining Clojure macro syntax

Tags: clojure

I defined an `unless` macro as follows:

```
user=> (defmacro unless [expr body] (list 'if expr nil body))
#'user/unless
user=> (unless (= 1 2) (println "Yo"))
Yo
```

As you can see it works fine.

Now, in Clojure a list can be defined in two ways:

```
; create a list
(list 1 2 3)

; shorter notation
'(1 2 3)
```

This means that the `unless` macro can be written without the `list` keyword. However, this results in a Java exception being thrown:

```
user=> (unless (= 1 2) (println "Yo"))
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: expr in this context
```

Can someone explain why this fails?

Comment: FYI, Clojure already has similar macros in core, called `when-not` and `if-not`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`'(foo bar baz)` is not a shortcut for `(list foo bar baz)`, it's a shortcut for `(quote (foo bar baz))`. While the list version will return a list containing the values of the variables foo, bar and baz, the version with `'` will return a list containing the symbols foo, bar and baz. (In other words `'(if expr nil body)` is the same as `(list 'if 'expr 'nil 'body)`.

This leads to an error because with the quoted version the macro expands to `(if expr nil body)` instead of `(if (= 1 2) nil (println "Yo"))` (because instead of substituting the macro's arguments for expr and body, it just returns the name expr and body (which are then seen as non-existent variables in the expanded code).

A shortcut that's useful in macro definitions is using `` ` ``. `` ` `` works like `'` (i.e. it quotes the expression following it), but it allows you to evaluate some subexpressions unquoted by using `~`. For example your macro could be rewritten as `` (defmacro unless [expr body] `(if ~expr nil ~body)) ``. The important thing here is that `expr` and `body` are unquoted with `~`. This way the expansion will contain their values instead of literally containing the names `expr` and `body`.

Comment: Furthermore `\`` will take care that the macro is hygienic. `list` should never ever be used to define macro expansions.

Comment: And a short comment for the macro itself: you can support implicit `do` to allow multiple forms in the macro body. `(defmacro unless [expr & body] \`(if ~expr nil (do ~@body)))`

Comment: using list is good if most of your forms would be escaped; `(defmacro my-if [pred then else] \`(if ~pred ~then ~else))` vs `(defmacro my-if [pred then else] (list \`if pred then else))`, for example.